# Can I create a sharepoint demo site that reverts back to a template

Tags: 2013

I have seen in the past using WordPress and Joomla that it's possible to install an app/module that will revert a site back to a point in time after a number hours or days.

I have a requirement for a SharePoint 2013 training site which we use to train departmental site managers. We want this to return to a stage in time either at a regular interval or on command.

Anyone know of a product or script to do this?

Edit: We cant use backup and restore as due to our environment we loose the Site Result types.

Comment: You should create and configure the site and then save it as a template, this way you can just create a new site and delete the old one instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option like `Site Recovery to a specific point` in SharePoint. Meanwhile, there are a lot of workarounds to do this.

1. **Save Site as a template.**

   - You can save a copy from the current site as a template.
   - Create a new site with this template for training purpose,
   - Once the training session finished, you can delete the used site and create a new one from the main template for the next training session.

> **Note**: the save site as a template is not working with Publishing
>   template and community template, read more at [missing save site as a
>   template](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/).

2. **Backup / Export & Restore / Import SharePoint Site.**

   - You can also take a backup (Export) at the specific time before the training session.
   - Once the training is finished, you can restore (Import) the backup on the same site to start a new training session with a fresh site.

> **Note**: You can run this operation in daily basis using task scheduler
>   or timer job.

See the details steps of [backup & restore site collection - import & export sub site using Central admin or PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2009/10/21/sharepoint-2010-granular-backup-restore-part-1/)

Answer (score 3):

For SharePoint on-premises I would also argue that database Backup and Restore is a simple and reliable approach.

Another one, that will also work with SharePoint Online, is to provision the training sites using the [PnP Provisioning Engine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/pnp-provisioning-engine-and-the-core-library) and the [PnP PowerShell Commands](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell). Use the [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/GetPnPProvisioningTemplate.md) cmdlet to create a template of your training site. Then create a pool a new training site collections and apply the template using the [Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/applypnpprovisioningtemplate) cmdlet. Delete used training sites and take new ones from the pool.

However, the PnP approach may also have limitations depending on the artifacts that you need to provision. It's also not too happy about Publishing sites.

Comment: we cant use backup and restore as we have a 2 farm setup and we dont mirror search databases (for various reasons ask Microsoft something to do with PLA), so if we fail over we would have to configure site collection result types.

Comment: Ok then you should definetely consider the PnP path